# Is there a way I can increase the shutter time in rpi zero camera v2.0?

Tags: raspbian, raspicam, pi-zero

I am using a raspberry pi zero camera v2.0 and I need to increase the shutter time to get more photons and images in raw format. How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `picamera` you can set the `shutter_speed` property. See the documentation: http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/recipes1.html chapter `3.5`